# Emacs - multiline search

Tags: emacs, full-text-search

Is there a module to do multiline search in Emacs ?

I have used `grep`, `pt` and now `ag`, and they are great. But sometimes when exploring a codebase you search for things that are on multiple lines (and therefore get nothing), but reducing the search to fewer words yields a lot of results.

Is there a way to get multiline search in Emacs in a whole project ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course there is. There are multiple ways.

You don't say what kind of search you are trying to do: single file? multiple buffers? regexp? Do you need a fixed list of search hits or do you want incremental search?

---

Here's one simple answer:

1. In a Dired buffer, mark some files you want to search, then hit `A`.
2. Type a regexp to match.  Use `C-q C-j` to enter a newline char to match. Hit `RET` to enter the regexp.

That searches through the marked files, stopping at each search hit in turn. Use `M-,` to go to the next hit, etc.

For example, to search for doc strings of variable definitions, search with this regexp or similar:

```
Search marked files (regexp): (defvar.*
.*"Non-nil
```

There's a newline char after the first `.*`, which you enter using `C-q C-j`.

---

There are lots of other ways to search in Emacs.  The best place to **start** is the [Search and Replace](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategorySearchAndReplace) category of Emacs Wiki. There you can find ways to search broken down by main characteristics and described.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my question : I am searching a project. I don't need regex search. Incremental search is preferable since it is for exploration.

Comment: The same tip about inserting newline chars applies to literal (i.e., non-regexp) search. `M-s a C-s` (command `dired-do-isearch`) does literal isearch of the marked files (e.g. a "project"). See also bookmarks for defining a set of files as a project (code base). See the [Project](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryProject) category on EmacsWiki for more info about defining, searching, etc. projects.